# How to capture Scroll event when mouse is not involved?

Tags: c#, winforms

Im capturing the Scroll event in a flowLayoutPanel that contains a bunch of controls inside (textboxes). If I move the scrollbar with the mouse the Scroll event is correctly captured. But If jump from control to control using the tab key and the scrollbar moves to give the textbox focus the event is not raised.
What can I do in that situation, I really need to capture no matter how the scroll is modified.

I uploaded a simple project where the problem could be shown http://1drv.ms/1UabHkv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the GotFocus event. There is also a LostFocus event.
It works for clicks, tabs, shift+tabs, and so on

```
textBox1.GotFocus += textBox1_ScrollEvent;
```

where `textBox1_ScrollEvent` is the event handler for the scrolling

Comment: but using that I will have to subscribe to every GotFocus event for each textbox that is inside the flowLayoutPanel and then in that code verify if the scroll has been moved. I think that is overkill, there must be a more clean approach. If no approach is found in a reasonable time I will put it as an answer.

Comment: As I say, due that no alternative was found I used this approach. Hopefully  it is not going to slow down too much the behaviour of the form. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are binding to the correct event. The docs for [ScrollableControl.Scroll Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.scroll(v=vs.110).aspx) state:

> The Scroll event occurs when the user scrolls through the client area by interacting with the scroll bars, or when the user navigates between controls and the active control scrolls into view. The Scroll event also occurs when you write code, such as setting the AutoScrollPosition property, that scrolls through the client area.

**Edit:**
It would seem that the MS documentation is indeed incorrect. I've tested using both your sample project and one I created and I'm experiencing the same behaviour where the `Scroll` event is not firing on tab or even on mousewheel.

It would seem that the best course of action would be to implement your own scrollbars and turn `Autoscroll` off for your `Panel`.

See the following SO question for mroe information: [How to use ScrollableControl with AutoScroll set to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286265/how-to-use-scrollablecontrol-with-autoscroll-set-to-false)

Comment: The description is beauty, the reality is different. I'm using exactly that event and the real behaviour don't correspond to that.

Comment: Could you provide your code so it can be replicated?

Comment: Sure give me a second to grab what is important

Comment: I added a simple project to show you the problem. I put the code on OneDrive, the link is in the question.

Comment: @mjsr I can reproduce your problem - updated answer.